# ios double quotes on dictionary when decimal point added

Tags: iphone, ios, json, dictionary

Im interacting with JSON, for "get" it works ok,

But with the "post", I have an error as the dictionary objects are surrounded with double quotes ""

and for the web service, i get an error for the double quotes,
the problem is that if i use a dot to indicate a decimal point then the double quotes appear,

> NSMutableDictionary *dicto = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

```
[dicto setObject:@"-33.82007932" forKey:@"Latitude"];

[dicto setObject:@"151.1850004" forKey:@"Longitude"];
[dicto setObject:@"10728" forKey:@"TransmissionAreaId"];
[dicto setObject:@"[11278,10747,10728,11503]" forKey:@"OtherTransmissionAreaIds"];
```

this is the log

> 2011-10-10 17:28:47.265 MySwitch[14632:707] the dictionary {
>       Latitude = "-33.820080";
>       Longitude = "151.1850004";
>       OtherTransmissionAreaIds = "[11278,10747,10728,11503]";
>       TransmissionAreaId = 10728;
>   }

so the `TransmissionAreaId = 10728`

appears ok, but if I test and use a decimal point ie: `TransmissionAreaId = 10728.01`

then i get the double quotes,

So how can i get rid of the double quotes??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the value you display in *NSLog*, it displays the value as string. Its a nature of *NSLog* that it adds double-quotes(`"`) around the values if they contain special characters other than alphanumeric values.

*NSLog* does this when it displays objects such as arrays and dictionaries. So, you won't see this behavior when you print just a string or float value directly in *NSLog*.

And, you have nothing to do with that than stop worrying!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSNumber` to save your value for the key. Something like-

```
[dicto setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:10723.01] forKey:@"TransmissionAreaId"];
```

Comment: hi thank you, i tried this way but on the nsLog it appears with double quotes as well, what could it be?, thanks!