# Add float value in dictionary in number format in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, double, nsdictionary

when we add int variable in dictionary, we need to convert it in NSNumber format

```
int f3 = 32;
int f4 = 35;

NSNumber* num3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:f3];
NSNumber* num4 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:f4];

NSDictionary *params1 = @{@"num3": num3, @"num4" : num4};
```

and when we see the dictionary value

```
num3 = 32;
num4 = 35;
```

this output comes in dictionary
but when we add float value in dictionary like

```
float f1 = 12.123456;
float f2 = 15.123456;

NSNumber* num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f1];
NSNumber* num2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f2];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"num1": num1, @"num2" : num2};
```

I am getting value inside dictionary are string instead of number mince i am getting value in double quote

```
num1 = "12.12346";
num2 = "15.12346";
```

Please any one help me... i want float value in dictionary but in numeric form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You right!...

```
float f1 = 12.123456;
float f2 = 15.123456;

NSNumber* num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f1];
NSNumber* num2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f2];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"num1": num1, @"num2" : num2};


NSLog(@"%@",[params valueForKey:@"num1"]);
```

Please get value from dictionary then you will get your answers.

This is look like string but value is float.

Please check images: [image: Check1]

[image: check2]
[image: check3]

Answer (score 0):

Values are storing into the NSNumber format. This is just the print representation of the `NSLog`. You can access the value like this

```
if ([[params objectForKey:@"num1"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    NSLog(@"Stored as Number");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Stored as String");
}
```

And the output is :

```
Stored as Number
```

Comment: yes, but i need to store float number in dict.

Comment: You're adding the number in dict in correct way. While your trying to print using `NSLog`, double quotes are added in the number. It is the nature of the NSLog. Please refer the below link:
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709247/ios-double-quotes-on-dictionary-when-decimal-point-added

Answer (score -1):

For above issue you have to use `Double` for not discard any value while converting to number or Dict

Please check below code:

```
float f1 = 12.123456;
float f2 = 15.123456;

double f3 = 12.123456;
double f4 = 15.123456;

NSNumber* num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f1];
NSNumber* num2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f2];
NSNumber* num3 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:f3];
NSNumber* num4 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:f4];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"num1": num1, @"num2" : num2,@"num3": num3, @"num4" : num4};
```

To get value back in float :

```
NSNumber *outNum1 = params[@"num1"];

NSLog(@"Float value = %f",outNum1.floatValue);
```

Log from above dict :

```
{
    num1 = "12.12346";
    num2 = "15.12346";
    num3 = "12.123456";
    num4 = "15.123456";
}
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: actually I need value in dict without double quote mince not in string format, I want numeric value in it.. i am not able to get that... :(

Comment: Its shows in double quote in Log but actual value is in number double & number float you can access like what i update in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
float f1 = 12.123456;
float f2 = 15.123456;
int yourDecimalLimit=1000000.0;
NSNumber* num1 = @((int)(f1*yourDecimalLimit)/yourDecimalLimit);
NSNumber* num2 = @((int)(f2*yourDecimalLimit)/yourDecimalLimit);
NSDictionary *params = @{@"num1": num1, @"num2" : num2};

output
{
num1 = "12.123456";
num2 = "15.123456";
}
```